# What is the use of type casting 'null' to any reference type in JAVA?

Tags: java, null

Is there anything which can be achieved by type casting null to say String ref type?

```
String s = null;
String t = (String) null;
```

Both does the same thing.

`sysout(s)` displays `null`

`sysout((String)null)` displays `null`

Comment: To distinguish between overloads.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose you have overloaded methods that take a single parameter, and you want to call one of them and pass null to it.

```
public void method1 (String param) {}

public void method1 (StringBuilder param) {}
```

If you make a call

```
method1 (null);
```

the code won't pass compilation, since both methods accept a `null` reference, and the compiler has no preference between the two overloads.

If you call

```
method1 ((String) null);
```

the first method will be called.

If you call

```
method1 ((StringBuilder) null);
```

the second method will be called.